# Android documentation

Tags: android, documentation

I want to do a documentation for an Android application. There's no problem with the java files but what about the xml-s? I think they are needed to understand some of the functionalities the application provides.

What is the proper way to visualize the xml files in the documentation or is it necessary to do it?

Comment: Add some examples please? This is a very vague question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the layout files need some explanation . The rest are pretty much self explanatory. You can probably use XML comments to explain a few things. You don't really need to document an XML file as its not exactly an API.